# How do I set an array size with a variable? C++

Tags: c++

I've got some code that defines a variable called 'size' then uses it but for some reason it doesn't work ; the error is "Expression did not evaluate to a constant"

```
int main()
{
    int size;
    int userValue;
    char input;

    do
    {

        cout << "Enter an int for the size of the array:" << endl;
        cin >> size;

        int a[size];

        cout << "Enter an integer between 1 and " << size << " to search for in the array." << endl;
        cin >> userValue;

        populateArray(a, size);

        linearSearch(a, size, userValue);
        binarySearch(a, size, userValue);

        cout << "Press 'y' and enter to run again or just enter to quit";
        cin.sync();
        cin.get(input);

    }while(input == 'y');
}
```

You can ignore the other functions as they are not called before the defining of my array, Ive tried setting size to a value, still doesn't work.

EDIT: forgot to mention

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: `int a[size]` is a variable length array - which is not a part of standard C++. You should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Technically you can't. An array size must be known at compile time. Some compilers offer an extension that allows Variable Length Arrays, but once you set the size, the size is fixed. Anyway, it looks like your compiler does not offer the VLA extension. Use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Ahh, so I do have to use Vectors ; alright, thanks anyways I was just making sure I had no other way of doing this!

Comment: @Wintér There are a lot of ways of doing this without `std::vector` but it's the easiest solution. If you refuse to use the standard library you can get away with `new[]` and `delete[]` but it's not recommended.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Memory managment would just cost more time I'll use vector for now, thanks anyways!

Comment: Micronag: Show a little caution with `using namespace std;` it's usually OK in small programs, but can result in some interesting errors.  More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @user4581301 I know that, right now I'm writing small programs to practice. (as you can see I just got done with Binary and Linear searching but I also covered alot of topics)

Answer (score -1):

Why not use a vector?

```
std::vector<int> a(size);
```

Also in C++, you cannot define an array with a variable like that.

Alternative:

```
int* a = new int[size];
// Do stuff
delete [] a;
```

Comment: In C you can. In C++ you can't. C/C++ isn't a thing.

Comment: variable length arrays **are allowed** in `C`. Not in `C++` though.

Comment: C99 has VLA as a mandatory feature while it's an optional feature in C11.

Comment: I didn't use a vector beacuse Im studying via an old youtube series, I coded everything myself (this is a program that detects how many iterations a binary search would do and a linear one) untill I came up with this problem, he leaves his code in a pastebin paste so I coppied it and when it still didn't work I just asked here

Comment: @Wintér Some compilers allow VLA as an extension, but it's not standard. If your instructor is using them without at least a disclaimer, I would strongly recommend looking for a new source of instruction.

Comment: My bad, old C doesn't allow this. I've edited it

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux his name on youtube is ReelLearning he uses eclipse and showed how to install it all but I use Visual Studio. He explains extremly well but my plan is to finish his youtube series and then move on to something bigger not sure how Im going to find something though

Comment: What if exception happened while "Do stuff"? Use [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

Comment: @Wintér Odds are the Youtuber uses the g++ compiler. Recommend checking their teachings [against a good book.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @boriaz50 Definitely, but that's more advanced C++

Comment: @user4581301 He is and thank you alot for the question you sent its going to be very very helpful for me!

Comment: @Wintér One place to find further skill-building projects is open source. Take a look at some of the projects that build tools that you are interested in or like using. Take a really close look at the project's mailing list, forum, newsgroup, whatever they use and get a read on how welcoming they are to newcommers first though. I think most are good, but some are sociopathic snake pits that are just not a good environment whether you're learning or not.